# Censoring data in a dataframe conditionally in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

In my `DATA`, I want to censor `n`s that are smaller than 10 and `percent`s `<.05` or `>.95` (***censoring criteria***).

**After** applying the censoring criteria above:

> Our goal is to not allow users to use one of the columns (ex. `n`) to figure out the other column (ex. `percent`) and vice versa.

But there is an issue. These `percent`s are based on each pair of `Met` values (`Yes`, `No`).

For example, the `percent` on the first row (`.791`) is from `n` of the first row divided by `sum` of the `n`s from the first row (`Met=="No`) and second row (`Met=="Yes"`).

Because of the relation between the pairs, censoring based on my censoring criteria alone, doesn't ensure that we achieve our goal above (*see my unsuccessful trial below*).

Is there a way to achieve my `Desire_output` below?

**P.S.** You may ask, in the `Desired_output`, why `65` on row 5 shouldn't be censored? Because `percent` on rows 5 and 6 are both already censored, so any `n > 10` can stay as is, since no one can figure `n` on row 6 (i.e., `n==1`) by looking at `n` at row 5 (i.e., `n==65`).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

DATA <- read.table(h=T,text=
" Ethnic_overall  EL_Type  Met  n   percent
         AmerInd  NeverEL  No 704   0.791
         AmerInd  NeverEL Yes 186   0.209
         AmerInd  Current  No  65   0.985
         AmerInd  Current Yes   1   0.015
         AmerInd   Former  No  50   0.847
         AmerInd   Former Yes   9   0.153")

# Doesn't produce Desired_output
mutate(DATA, percent_new =
         ifelse(percent < .05, "<5%", ifelse(percent > .95, ">95%", percent(percent))),
       n = ifelse(n < 10 | percent %in% c("<5%",">95%"), "*", n) )

# Current unsuccessful output:
  Ethnic_overall EL_Type  Met   n percent_new
1        AmerInd NeverEL  No 704       79.1%
2        AmerInd NeverEL Yes 186       20.9%
3        AmerInd Current  No  65        >95%
4        AmerInd Current Yes   *         <5%
5        AmerInd  Former  No  50       84.7%
6        AmerInd  Former Yes   *       15.3%

# Desired_output:
  Ethnic_overall EL_Type Met   n percent_new
1        AmerInd NeverEL  No 704       79.1%
2        AmerInd NeverEL Yes 186       20.9%
3        AmerInd Current  No  65        >95%
4        AmerInd Current Yes  *          <5%
5        AmerInd  Former  No  *        84.7%
6        AmerInd  Former Yes  *        15.3%
```

Comment: Why is 65 not censored? Your criteria states: I want to censor ns that are smaller than 10 and percents <.05 or *>.95*. Are you saying (smaller than 10 and percents < 0.05) or percents > 0.95 OR smaller than 10 and (percents < 0.05 or 0.95)?

Comment: @LMc, 65 is not censored because a user has no way to figure out how 65 relates to `< 0.05` or `>.95` as these two are themselves censored. The goal is not to allow users to use one of the columns (ex. n) to figure out the other column (ex. percent) and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues are 2 fold.  One, you have multiple "if" conditions for `ifelse()`, which I believe only accepts a binary syllogism.  Second, you are trying to combine numeric and character datatypes in a single column, which "dplyr" will throw a fit about.  You can overcome #1 by using `case_when()` instead of `ifelse(),` as the former accepts multiple conditions to test before writing the default value.  To overcome the second challenge, simply coerce the default value to a character variable using `as.character().`  Here is the full solution, which gives your desired output.

```
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)

DATA <- read.table(h=T,text=
                     " Ethnic_overall  EL_Type  Met  n   percent
         AmerInd  NeverEL  No 704   0.791
         AmerInd  NeverEL Yes 186   0.209
         AmerInd  Current  No  65   0.985
         AmerInd  Current Yes   1   0.015
         AmerInd   Former  No  50   0.847
         AmerInd   Former Yes   9   0.153")

mutate(DATA, percent_new =
         case_when(percent < .05 ~ "<5%", 
                   percent > .95~ ">95%", 
                   TRUE~as.character(percent))) %>% 
      mutate(n = case_when(n < 10~"*",
                     percent_new %in% c("<5%",">95%") ~ "*",
                     TRUE~as.character(n)), test_met=lead(Met), test_n=lead(n)) %>% 
   mutate(n=case_when(test_n=="*" & test_met=="Yes"~"*",
                      TRUE~n)) %>%  select(-c(test_n, test_met))
```

Here is the output:

```
  Ethnic_overall EL_Type Met   n percent percent_new
1        AmerInd NeverEL  No 704   0.791       0.791
2        AmerInd NeverEL Yes 186   0.209       0.209
3        AmerInd Current  No   *   0.985        >95%
4        AmerInd Current Yes   *   0.015         <5%
5        AmerInd  Former  No   *   0.847       0.847
6        AmerInd  Former Yes   *   0.153       0.153
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code doesn't produce the `Desired_output` as shown in my post (it doesn't censor `n==50` on row 5). I would imagine that `lead()` or `lag()` might have a role to play here.

Comment: Unfortunately, still your code doesn't produce the `Desired_output` as shown in my post (it doesn't censor `n==50` on row 5).

Comment: Hopefully the third time is the charm.  You were on to something with `lead()` and `lag()`.  I added two test variables in the second call to `mutate()`, "test_n" and "test_met" which copy the next row's values of "n" and "met," respectively.  I added one more call to `mutate()` to screen values where "test_n" was equal to "*" and "test_met" was equal to "yes."  Finally I got rid of those two test columns with a call to `select()`.  Since I don't know the intricacies of your data you might have to add or change the logical in the final call to `mutate()` to ensure you are screening correctly..

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately, still your code doesn't produce the `Desired_output` as shown in my post (it erroneously censors `n==65` on row 3). In this case, because `percent` on rows 5 and 6 are both already censored, any `n > 10` can stay as is, since no one can figure `n` on row 6 (i.e., `n==1`) by looking at `n` at row 5 (i.e., `n==65`).